# To what group does coconut plant belong?

Tags: osmoregulation

I've tried looking it up but I couldn't find an answer. Could someone please tell me to what group of plants do coconuts belong depending upon the natural availability of water?

Comment: what do you mean by "group" (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taxonomic_rank) and what relevance is the availability of water?

Comment: I mean it's neither in halophytes nor in hydrophytes. Does it have a separate classification on the basis of availability of water in its natural habitat?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In terms of taxonomy and morphology:

> Although coconut trees display considerable morphological diversity,
>   they are considered taxonomically a single species (and the only
>   species) within the genus *Cocos*. Based on stature and breeding,
>   coconut cultivars can be divided into two groups: tall and dwarf.
>   The former typically grows up to 35 to 40 meters and is mainly
>   outcrossing, whereas the latter can only grow up to 25 to 30 meters
>   and usually is selfing. Dwarf coconuts, which are less common than the
>   tall variety, are usually found growing close to humans and have
>   traits that likely result from human selection.

http://journals.plos.org/plosone/article?id=10.1371/journal.pone.0074736

I've found little information about whether or not they are halophytes, hydrophytes, xerophytes,or mesophytes - but according to a [Google Book](https://books.googleca/books?id=sA6qilydg_kC&pg=PA570&lpg=PA570&dq=Cocos%20nucifera%20halophyte&source=bl&ots=tXLMO-c-o4&sig=h6GgoVW7wYb8Iz3o7uUs8-jRsZY&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiMuazR7v_KAhUCyYMKHX2jCHkQ6AEIIDAC#v=onepage&q=Cocos%20nucifera%20halophyte&f=false), a number of crops are widely cultivated in non-saline soils, including *Cocos nucifera* (coconuts). [Another Google book](https://books.google.ca/books?id=yyYjAQAAIAAJ&pg=PA428&lpg=PA428&dq=are%20coconuts%20halophytes,%20hydrophytes,%20xerophytes,%20mesophytes&source=bl&ots=TKKHMtylJp&sig=aXPEKWaPiNIXFL2xT9bLi7vlV8w&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjM2tuM9P_KAhXrmoMKHfAhA5oQ6AEIMDAD#v=onepage&q=coconut&f=false) with a lot of information about coconuts states this: Some experiments show that a small quantity of salt added to the tree roots is beneficial.

*Cocos nucifera* also love sunlight, so they can be considered heliophytes.